# Object won't snap to other object

Tags: objects, snapping

I'm unable to snap duplicated objects.

When I hit <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>35</kbd> (or any other axis), there is gap between the 2 objects. I want it to snap to it, or stick closely to the original object.

[image]

I'm following a tutorial.

[image]

Comment: Do you have snap-to-grid turned on? Are the origins of the objects right? Is there a difference between the two images?

Comment: hey solved it snap to grid was turned off thank you